# How to print Specific Part of String in Dart?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

I want to print specific part of String in dart
Example:

```
String sample = "Hello World";
```

Output:

```
llo Wor
```

Like In Python We do this simply By:

```
print(sample[2:-2])
```

But How to achieve this in Dart Language

If you know the Solution then answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do this With [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/substring.html) Method In Dart
Like This:

```
String sample = "hello world";
print(sample.subString(2,7);
```

if You want to Specify Number of Letters From End Then Do This.

```
print(sample.subString(2,sample.length-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/substring.html)

```
String sample = "Hello World";
```

Output:

```
llo Wor
```

code in dart

```
print(sample.substring(2, 9));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/substring.html) method.

like so:

```dart
print(helloWorldText.substring(2, helloWorldText.length -2));
```

Here is the example in Dartpad.
https://dartpad.dev/c15474ddb5402fef40e73332a41642cd?null_safety=true